# Find all local maximum and minimum of $f$, which is $1$ if the decimal expansion contains a $5$ and $0$ otherwise.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find all local maximum and minimum points of $f$.

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if the decimal expansion of $x$ contains a 5} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

The answer states that $x$ is a local minimum point if its decimal expansion does not contain a $5$. It is a local maximum point if its decimal expansion contains exactly one $5$ that is followed by an infinite string of $9$'s. In all other cases, $x$ is both a local maximum point and a local minimum point.

I don't fully understand the answer.

Clearly if its decimal expansion does not contain a $5$ then it is a local minimum point. But why is it not a local maximum point? Also, if its decimal expansion contains exactly one $5$ that is followed by an infinite string of $9$'s, then it is clearly a local maximum point, but why is it not a local minimum? Finally, why are all other cases both local minimum and maximum?

Comment: Could you fill in your textbook's definitions of local minimum and maximum point?

Comment: If $f$ well-defined? If $x$ has two representations, for example $x=0.75000\ldots = 0.74999\ldots$, then what is $f(x)$? One or zero?

Comment: After you say "I don't fully understand the answer", you've got minimum and maximum mixed up. ... In this problem, 0.4 (for instance) would be a local maximum iff any number arbitrarily close to 0.4 has no 5s in its expansion. Hence, to show that 0.4 is not a local maximum, you need to find numbers close to 0.4 which _do_ have a 5 in their expansion. Such numbers include 0.45, 0.405, 0.4005, etc. For each of these numbers $x$, $f(x)=1$, but $f(0.4)=0$. Hence $f(0.4)\not>f(x)$ for _all_ $x$ close to 0.4, and so 0.4 is not a local maximum.

Comment: @Jeppe: The finite representation 0.75 probably takes precedence.

Comment: @CarlHeckman But the question mentions a situation where the expansion ends in "an infinite string of 9s".

Comment: I wasn't answering that part of the question, only "But why is it not a local maximum [sic] point?"

Comment: I agree with you. I find the answer provided in the 4th edition confusing. I feel like there are 3 types of points as far as I can tell. Points that are NEITHER max/mins (for example, 0.50 or 0.050, or... etc...because to the left are a collection of points with no 5's in the decimal representation and to the right are a collection of points that will always have at least one 5 in the representation), points like 0.51, which will be simultaneously max and mins (evaluating to 1), and points like 0.49, which will be simultaneously max and mins (evaluating to 0).

Comment: That is to say, I feel like the function is just line segments of variable length that jump between evaluations of purely 1 or purely 0.